# JQUERY - Show hidden div on TABLE mouse over

Tags: jquery

Sorry for little knowledge on JQuery. 
I have been try and searching to sort this problem for a day or so and i have searched this site for answers, but cant get the finalized solution.

Basically i am working a very limited ECOM site, which provides limited development functionality, the only way to manipulate and change elements is to use client side language.

Basically i have a very very dirty html table generated on the fly, with a table class and unique TR ID for each product. The products are show in their own table.

I am wanting to show an hidden div when the user mouse-overs the table. I have tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table.newspaper-d tr[id^=product_]').hover(function () {
        $(this).find("div.tools").show();
    }, function () {
        $(this).find("div.tools").hide();
    });
});
```

Which works to some extent, but it only works when hovering over the div.

Mark up of HTML example is tables with class and each TR has a unique row of product_ - (ID is contactenated) ie product_134 is one, product_324, product_323 etc etc

```
<tbody>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table class="newspaper-d" border="0" style="width:250px; float:left;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="product_13633">
                        <td>

                            KKKK 

                            <div class="tools" style="display: none;">
                                <div class="add-to-basket-product">
                                    <div class="inner-add-to-basket-product">
                                        <a href="javascript:addToCart(13633);">

                                            ADD TO CART

                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="200">
                                            <div class="product-category-pic" align="center">
                                                <a href="/Descombes-Brouilly-VV-2011-818221/">
                                                    <img class="image-thumb" border="0" src="/product_images/16/3883/thumb-descombes-brouilly-vv-2011.jpg" title="Descombes Brouilly VV 2011" alt="Descombes Brouilly VV 2011"></img>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <table cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td height="36" align="center">


                                           PRODUCT PRODUCT PRODUCT

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <div class="product-category-details"></div>
                            <div class="add-to-basket-product"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Thanks guys

Comment: share the html example

Comment: I see an issue with your selector: `tr[id^=product_]` should be `tr[id^="product_"]` -- you need quotes around the attribute text.

Comment: you code works fine you are missing something else http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/wvcw4s5c/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your last comment I would do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table.newspaper-d').hover(function () {
        $(this).find("div.tools").show();
    }, function () {
        $(this).find("div.tools").hide();
    });
});
```

Hovering the full table, toggle the visibility of the div.

You can check it un this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/benjasHu/kLko76sa/

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually works just fine as it is.  The attribute selector can either be `tr[id^=product_]` or `tr[id^="product_"]`, there is no difference in how they operate.  I'm assuming there's something going on with your markup that makes the selection work unexpectedly, and if you would post a sample of your html, I'd be happy to adjust my fiddle to reflect what you need.

fiddle with a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/autoboxer/jLnj4gas/2/

Cheers,
autoboxer

Edit: I've updated my fiddle based on the markup you posted.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt replies people. Excellent.

The HTML is follows. Again, i dont have access to this to change (its a mess with nested tables)
Just to follow up, the code works IF i hover over where the div is, i want it show the div when hovering over the full table.Its basically a product page with multiple products in a grid format, hence the unique ROW ID

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the "CLASS" selector in place of "ID" selector, since the TR contains CLASS and not ID.

TRY THE CODE BELOW:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('table.newspaper-d tr[class^="product_"]').hover(function () {
    $(this).find("div.tools").show();
}, function () {
    $(this).find("div.tools").hide();
});
});
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3ree4x66/5/)